# does tls.Config.VerifyPeerCertificate bypass the default provided checks in golang?

Tags: go, ssl, tls1.2

I want to implement stricter checks for allowing only few common names in a certificate.

I was looking at this commit [https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/26654/4/src/crypto/tls/handshake_client.go#310](https://stackoverflow.com)

It looks to me as though the verifyPeerCertificate just augments the certificate verification process instead of bypassing the existing checks and solely depending on the custom implementation.

Is this understanding right ? I do see contrasting answers on stack overflow

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls) clearly describes the behavior. To cite:

> ```
> // VerifyPeerCertificate, if not nil, is called after normal
> // certificate verification by either a TLS client or server. It
> // receives the raw ASN.1 certificates provided by the peer and also
> // any verified chains that normal processing found. If it returns a
> // non-nil error, the handshake is aborted and that error results.
> //
> // If normal verification fails then the handshake will abort before
> // considering this callback. ...
> ```

So, unless `InsecureSkipVerify` is true (see later) it will verify the certificate the normal way. And it will fail if this built-in validation failed, i.e. not even call `VerifyPeerCertificate` in this case. This means that `VerifyPeerCertificate` cannot override the built-in validation to make it pass, but it can add additional constraints to the certificate and override a positive result of the built-in validation to make it fail.

> ```
> //                        ... If normal verification is disabled (on the
> // client when InsecureSkipVerify is set, or on a server when ClientAuth is
> // RequestClientCert or RequireAnyClientCert), then this callback will be
> // considered but the verifiedChains argument will always be nil. When
> // ClientAuth is NoClientCert, this callback is not called on the server.
> // rawCerts may be empty on the server if ClientAuth is RequestClientCert or
> // VerifyClientCertIfGiven.
> ```

Thus when `InsecureSkipVerify` is true then `VerifyPeerCertificate` is solely responsible for the validation and no built-in validation will be done.